# Colors wrong when using nd2reader to convert .nd2 to images

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, png, tiff

I am using ND2reader to take each color channel (3 in my case) combine and export to a tif. This is an example of what it should look like:
[Original image exported from Nis Elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7a7h.jpg)

but instead I get this image which seems like the colors are completely off.
[Image from exported using my script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7Lu6.png)

doing an image analysis and comparison using ImageMagick it seems like my script is just not saving it as 16 bit or combining as 16 bit at all. Any thoughts?

Image from script -> `ImageFromND2_hour0.frame0.png PNG 512x512 512x512+0+0 8-bit sRGB 400303B 0.000u 0:00.002`
Image From NisElements -> `31.5.21 alk ascending concentration_croppedt01xy01.tif TIFF 512x512 512x512+0+0 16-bit sRGB 1.51925MiB 0.031u 0:00.035`

Here is my code:

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
from nd2reader import ND2Reader, legacy
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
# Print iterations progress

filelocation = 'Nd2 Conversion\\31.5.21 ALK ascending concentration_Cropped.nd2'
from nd2reader import ND2Reader
with ND2Reader(filelocation) as images:
    l = len(images) * images[0].metadata['fields_of_view'][-1]
    addition = 100 / l
    np.set_printoptions(precision=3)
    numberoffiles = 0
    for x in range(len(images)):
        for fov in images[x].metadata['fields_of_view']:
            c0 = images.parser.get_image_by_attributes(frame_number=x,field_of_view=fov,channel=0,z_level=0,height=512,width=512)
            c1 = images.parser.get_image_by_attributes(frame_number=x,field_of_view=fov,channel=1,z_level=0,height=512,width=512)
            c2 = images.parser.get_image_by_attributes(frame_number=x,field_of_view=fov,channel=2,z_level=0,height=512,width=512)
            no_img = 3
            imagefinal = c0/no_img + c1/no_img + c2/no_img
            plt.imsave("Nd2 Conversion\\ALK Cropped Python\\ImageFromND2_hour" + str(x) + ".frame" + str(fov) + ".png", imagefinal)
            numberoffiles += 1

print("Complete!")
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```